# Getting error in python as "**The truth value of a Series is ambiguous"

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I am getting the below error when I am trying to perform an if statement and assigning it back to a dataframe column

**The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

```
def cal_test():
    if IP['Type'] == 'ABC':
        (IP['tt'] + ' ' + IP[abc])
    else:
        IP[tt]

IP['column_name']  =   cal_test()
```

Comment: So did you search for that error? There are many existing Q&As covering this behaviour.

Comment: Should your function have a return statement? Also `IP['tt']` vs `IP[tt]` I am unsure if this is what is intended or is a typo, though without an example of the data it is difficult to know. I would suggest taking a look at the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page and trying to create an example that allows someone answering the question to copy and paste your code in order to reproduce the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IP['column_name'] = IP['tt']
IP.loc[IP['Type'] == 'ABC', 'column_name'] = IP['tt'] + ' ' + IP['abc']
```

Answer (score -1):

The expression:

```
IP['Type'] == 'ABC'
```

means to compare a column "Type" of dataframe `IP` against a string `"ABC"`, which of course ambiguous -- do you want it to fail because you are comparing apple to orange or do you mean if any of the item in the column match the string?

The right way to compare itemize is `IP['Type'].eq('ABC')` which returns you a column (i.e., series) of boolean value, or you can use `any` or `all` to mean any value in the column or all values in the column do the match.

And, your function returns nothing. So you cannot possibly put anything "back" to the dataframe. Try do this instead:

```
IP['column_name'] = IP.apply(
    lambda row: (row['tt']+' '+row['abc']) if row['Type'] == 'ABC' else
                row['tt'],
    axis=1
)
```

Comment: Not the downvote, but the expression is not ambiguous; it returns a Series with elementwise comparisons of each value in `IP.Type` with the expression. What’s ambiguous is when you write `if Series_of_booleans`. You need a single truth value and providing a Series doesn’t lead to an unambiguous comparison